# Листки и листики

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, существительные

Правильно ли так говорить о листьях дерева — **листки**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, так можно говорить, причем авторы словарей никаких особенностей или ограничений в употреблении не указывают.

[ЛИСТ](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-academ-term-32359.htm) (МАС) -а, *мн.* листья, -ьев и листы, -ов, *м.*
1. (*мн.* листья и листы). Тонкая зеленая пластинка различной формы на черенке (орган воздушного питания и газообмена у растения).
*Воздух насыщен ароматом молодых смолистых **листов** тополей, берез и цветущей ивы* (М. Пришвин. Фацелия).

[ЛИСТОК](http://endic.ru/academic/Listok-17963.html) (МАС) -тка́, *м.*
1. *уменьш.* к лист (в 1 и 2 знач.); то же, что лист.

*В саду **листки берёз**, без шороха срываясь,

Средь тонких паутин, как бабочки, блестят

И, слабо по ветвям цепляясь и качаясь,

На блёклую траву беспомощно летят.*
И. Бунин. Затишье

*Ведь даром что почищены,

Порезаны в куски,

И дарят ароматы им

**Лавровые листки**...*
О. Арефьева

Стоит отметить, что в обычной речи, конечно же, чаще употребляется собирательное существительное *листва* или просто *листья*, если уж совсем-совсем маленькие, то — *листочки*.

Answer (score 3):

Листок — листки, листик — листики. В общем-то, это синонимы. Листок — уменьшительное к "лист" (и лист дерева, и лист бумаги), листик — уменьшительно-ласкательное к нему же, обе формы разговорные.

Другое дело, что в современном языке появились значения "бланк", "карточка", "карта", "листовка", "табель", "ведомостичка", "газета", чаще стали употреблять **листок** в значении *лист бумаги*, а **листик** в значении *маленький лист дерева*, **листок** остался в употреблении поэтов как **одинокий лист**, поэтому сочетание *листки дерева* уже воспринимается  как некорректное — много одиноких листков трудно представить, в отличие от листков бумаги.

Но это скорее стилистическое предпочтение, а не речевая ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно, но так говорят о малом количестве. Если их много, то это листья или листва.

Михаил Лермонтов "Листок"
**Дубовый листок** оторвался от ветки родимой
И в степь укатился, жестокою бурей гонимый;
Засох и увял он от холода, зноя и горя
И вот, наконец, докатился до Черного моря.

Виктор Чалов "Сухое, кривое деревце"
Вот ближе все метр за метром
Шершавый язык песка,
На ветках, обглоданных ветром,
Осталось лишь **два листка**.

Владимир Михайлов "Стебелек и **два листка**".

В толковых словарях у слова "листок" такое значение тоже присутствует.